# How to filter mysql.log whole query?

Tags: mysql, logging, grep

Hello I have a problem with filtering mysql.log (general log). I am trying to filter whole query, but in log file lines are split by newline and using GREP shows only part of the query.

Command

```
tail -n 2000000 mysql.log | grep '016198498'
```

Produces only this - without **UPDATE table SET etc.** just part of the code

```
inm = '016198498',
```

Any solution to grep whole query with timestamp ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution has been found. You can grep lines before and after. e.g. 10 lines before and 10 lines after which provides sufficient output for me in this case.

tail -n 3000000 mysql.log | grep -B 10 -A 10 '016198498'

Comment: If you want 10 before and after, you can directly use `-C 10` with `grep`.